# javaScript / map - добавить элемент массив по условию

Tags: javascript

У меня есть 2 массива c объектами:

```
  arr1 = [{},{},...]
  arr2 = [{},{},...]
```

Цель по условию добавить в объекты 1-го массива новый ключ с массивом значений.
Добавить объект сложности не вызывает, но не получается.
Пример:

```
  const newArr = arr1.map(i1 => {
    arr2.forEach(i2 => {
        if (i1.id === i2.id) {
            i1.newObj = [{exp1: i2.example1, exp2: i2.example2}]
        }
    });
    return i1
});
```

Так происходит перезапись значения массива и в итоге остается только последнее  значение.
Как не заменять, а добавлять в массив значения по выполнению условия?

Comment: Скажите лучше что у вас есть в начале и что вам надо

Comment: Как и описано выше, есть 2 массива объектов и если определенные значения объектов, в данном случае id, совпадают, то в первый массив, в объект, который соответствует условию - добавить новый ключ, с массивом значений из объекта 2-го массива.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так (впрочем использование двух вложенных циклов неэффективно):

```
void (i1.newObj ||= []).push({exp1: i2.example1, exp2: i2.example2})
```

PS: А за имена переменных и полей руки поотрывать.

Comment: Пример для наглядности тут накидал, отсюда и названия переменных. Видимо фантазии на большее не хватило, извиняюсь, если глаза режет :)
Это пример из C ЯП? Немного не понимаю, что здесь "||=", если писать для javascript :(
"впрочем использование двух вложенных циклов неэффективно" - если подскажите использование более подходящего метода для данной задачи - буду благодарен :)

Comment: @Alex, это js. [`||=` на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment). Эффективнее сделать через словарь.

Comment: Смутил void, с которым не был знаком. Спасибо, все получилось. Обязательно попробую сделать вариант через словарь :)